# CONDITIONAL UPDATE DATA IN ACCESS TABLE VIA ACCESS FORM

Tags: ms-access

to be precise, I am trying to develop a Form (with Subform) (VOUCHER FORM) and I don't want access to save it unless the sum of Debit and Credit columns are equal. I have created two text boxes showing sum of debit and sum of credit in form. But Don't know how to stop access form to update data in my voucher table if the said condition is not satisfied.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I like the downvoter claiming the question to be _too broad_ ...!

Answer (score 0):

Use the BeforeUpdate event:

```
If Not IsNull(Me!Debit.Value + Me!Credit.Value) Then
    Cancel = (Nz(Me!Debit.Value, 0) <> Nz(Me!Credit.Value, 0))
End If

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Debit and Credit must match." 
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav,
Please note that, this solution is not completely working as after this code form directly goes for this check and doesn't allow me to complete the entries.
Hence it will always give the message that Dr Cr mismatch.
Can you please tell me how to stop it from checking unless I have completed all my entries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, see the last edit checking for empty textboxes.